# Не двигается player на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
import pygame
from pygame.constants import QUIT
pygame.init()

HEIGHT = 800
WIDTH = 1200

COLOR_WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
COLOR_BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

main_display = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))


player_size = (30, 30)
player = pygame.Surface((player_size))
player.fill((COLOR_WHITE))
player_rect = player.get_rect()
player_speed = [1, 1]
main_display.blit(player, player_rect)
player_rect = player_rect.move(player_speed)
pygame.display.flip(COLOR_BLACK)
playing = True

while playing: 
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT: 
      playing = False
```

Comment: так а вы и не говорите ему двигаться. вы отрисовали его один раз и забыли про него

Comment: я думал, что player_rect даёт команду двигаться, разве нет?

Comment: `player_rect.move` двигает, но вы двигаете только один раз - при старте программы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуй так:

```
import pygame
from pygame.constants import QUIT

pygame.init()

HEIGHT = 800
WIDTH = 1200

COLOR_WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
COLOR_BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

main_display = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

player_size = (30, 30)
player = pygame.Surface(player_size)
player.fill(COLOR_WHITE)
player_rect = player.get_rect()
player_speed = [1, 1]

playing = True

while playing:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            playing = False

    # Clear the screen
    main_display.fill(COLOR_BLACK)

    # Update player position
    player_rect = player_rect.move(player_speed)

    # Draw the player
    main_display.blit(player, player_rect)

    # Update the display
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: постарайтесь добавлять более развёрнутые ответы, дополнить ответ можно нажав кнопку [edit]

Comment: работает, спасибо большое

Comment: хорошо если вам помог мой ответ отметьте его как верный